# How to Get Static Var Inside Class

Tags: c++

I am new for C++, I want to do some thing like the Java language below without create an object, how do I do that?

```
public class ClassA {
    **public static final NAME = "ClassA";**
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(**ClassA.NAME**);
    }
}
```

Comment: [I'd recommended starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## C++98

```
class ClassA {
public:
    static const std::string Name;
};

const std::string ClassA::Name = "ClassA";

int main()
{
    std::cout << ClassA::Name << std::endl;
}
```

## C++17

```
class ClassA {
public:
    static inline const std::string Name = "ClassA";
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << ClassA::Name << std::endl;
}
```

## C++20

(cannot test it yet)

```
class ClassA {
public:
    static constexpr std::string Name = "ClassA";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ClassA::Name << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static const std::string NAME = "ClassA";

int main()
{
    std::cout << NAME;
}
```